# Get the inverse of a dataframe column in terms of rows with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an original dataframe `df0` with a number of values, based on this dataframe I have a second dateframe where some the original values are `NaN`, `df1`.

```
import pandas as pd
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,None,4,5,6,None,8,None,10,11,None,13,None,None]})
```

I need a `df2` to be the inverse of `df1` in terms of rows with `NaN`. Every row which is `NaN` in df1 should get its original value back from `df0` and rows which are not `NaN` must become `NaN` such that I get the following dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [None,None,3,None,None,None,7,None,9,None,None,12,None,14,15]})
```

What is the best way to go about this if it were a larger dataset?

Comment: So need replace all columns, correct?

Comment: I mean to replace only the col1 column, in my actual data set there are multiple other columns which must stay as is. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Ok, answer was edited. So need replace all columns by `col1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### masking all columns

If you need to mask **all columns**, use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) OR [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df2 = df0.mask(df1['col1'].notna())
# or
df2 = df0.where(df1['col1'].isna())
```

output:

```
    col1
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    7.0
7    NaN
8    9.0
9    NaN
10   NaN
11  12.0
12   NaN
13  14.0
14  15.0
```

##### masking only "col1"

If you just need to replace col1 and leave potential other columns intact rather use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df2 = df0.assign(col1=df0['col1'].mask(df1['col1'].notna()))
```

Comment: I needed the second option to keep others intact yes, thank you!

Comment: @BasR it wasn't sure given the example, but glad it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) for replace one column by another DataFrame, only necessary same index in both:

```
df0['col1'] = df0['col1'].where(df1['col1'].isna())
print (df0)
    col1
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    7.0
7    NaN
8    9.0
9    NaN
10   NaN
11  12.0
12   NaN
13  14.0
14  15.0
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df0.loc[df1['col1'].notna(), 'col1'] = np.nan
```